# UiPath Apps deployment and migration to another tenant

Tags: azure, uipath, rpa, uipath-apps

Our platform is UiPath Cloud Orchestrator with DEV/Test/Prod tenants. The Robots are hosted on Azure Windows instances for DEV / Test / Prod.

I created an UiPath App to upload an Excel file, store it in a storage bucket, then start a unattended process to read the excel file.

The UiPath app points and binds to the storage bucket and process in the DEV tenant.

I would like to deploy and migrate the UiPath app to point to the Test Tenant. It seems like that to point to Test, I have to change the app in the app studio to switch the pointers/bindings for the process and storage bucket and replace them and change or confirm the UI elements are correct.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to do migrate the app to another tenant for the UiPath apps?

It does not seem right to have to change the pointers this way. It only just allows us to point to one tenant at a time so hard to really have DEV/Test/Prod instances of the Uipath app without having copies of the app for each tenant.

I can export the app (.uiapp file) and import the file across Cloud platforms but not across the tenants without changing the name of the app. The .uiapp file seems to be a json format with the bindings in the file with specific ids etc. Changing the pointers and bindings here would be error prone as well.

I have looked through the documentation, the uipath academy training and the forums which do not provide an answer.

Appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 1):

As your using the Azure Host, I'm assuming that you might be using the Azure DevOps for your packaging and publishing.

Have a look at the package below:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=uipath.vsts-uipath-package

You can set the Tenancy level so that it's packaged for that specific tenant, can create any assets etc.

Comment: Thanks for the information above. I looked at the Azure pipeline UiPath integration link that you provided above. I do not see how it can apply to UiPath Apps deployment and tenant. It does not mention UiPath Apps at all.